# sIFR 3 r 436 not displaying in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, sifr, sifr3

I am new to sIFR and I am unable to get the fonts to display properly in IE7.  I get an "Expected Identifier, String or Number" error, which I don't know how to troubleshoot.

Here is my dev link: http://paradigm-aero.bigrigmedia.com/test.html

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least one) a comma before the closing curly brace:

```
sIFR.replace(centurygothic, {
  selector: '.century12',
  css: [ '.sIFR-root { color: #666666; leading: 1; letter-spacing: 1; text-transform: uppercase; }' ,'a { text-decoration: none }' ,'a:link {   color: #112343 }' ,'a:hover { color: #E31824 }' ], wmode: 'transparent',  preventWrap: true,
  forceWidth: true,
  fitExactly: true,
  forceSingleLine: true,
});
```

This causes a syntax error in IE.

Comment: Hi Mark,

I originally made sure I removed all comas before the closing brackets. I'm not sure I see the coma you are referring to. 

I removed all unused selectors to simplify. Is there something else I am doing wrong?